# UITableView loading Issues with images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have set up my application to use Parse.  I am uploading images.  When the request is sent to parse it stores all of my objects in an array 'wallObjectsArray'.  The images however when i set them to be viewed in my UITableview are have display problems.  The initially show up then some will disappear until i refresh the UITableView.  I have used SDWebImage before but i didn't think i would need it with this as all of the images are stored in my array already, i just want to display them and scroll through UITableView smoothly.  I am using a customCell class.  My code below

```
self.customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        PFObject *wallObject = [self.wallObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    _image = (PFFile *)[wallObject objectForKey:@"image"];

    self.customCell.profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:_image.getData];
```

Comment: What's your declaration for `_image`? Looks like it might be a member variable? On first glance it looks like all your images are hooked up to this one variable, which would explain bizarre behaviour.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put that this is all within - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    _image is declared at the top of my implementation file using @property PFFile *image;  I think it's a cache issue with UITableViewCells?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a single member var as a cache for all the image data. There may be threading issues if it's used elsewhere. Also the property is not declared `strong` - I'm wondering about your other declarations. Can you post some more code?